# I want to print parent url in my iframe. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to print parent domain name in my iframe. Is it possible? Share your idea. Thanks in advance. :)

[image]

Parent page

```
<html><head><title></title></head>
<frameset border="0" rows="100%,*" cols="100%" frameborder="no">
<frame name="TopFrame" scrolling="yes" noresize src="http://test.com/test.php">
<frame name="BottomFrame" scrolling="no" noresize></frameset>
</html>
```

iframe page (test.php)

```
<body>
<h1 align="center">Parent Domain Name</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/04/16/getting-the-url-of-an-iframes-parent/

Comment: `window.parent.document.location.href`?

Comment: window.parent.document.location.href   is not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass whatever value you like to the PHP page and then output this within the frame view?

```
<frame name="TopFrame" scrolling="yes" noresize src="http://test.com/test.php?domain=mydomain.com">
```

Then in test.php

```
<h1 align="center"><?php echo $_GET['domain']; ?></h1>
```

Alternatively,

You could also try using the `window.parent.document.location.href` JavaScript as mentioned by putvande. Then use `document.writeln` or jQuery to add the value to the page. You could get the domain name with something like: `window.parent.document.location.href.split("/")[2]`.